# Please tell steps for running asm file in dosbox and about including libraries in the code

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32, masm32, dosbox

> [image]

---

The image shows the error i encounter in dosbox

I am writing code for finding nth term of fibonnaci sequence using recursion in assembly language. I used call PutDec and call Getdec procedures in my code for taking input and for printing resp. When I run the code its showing error, L2029: PUTDEC, PUTSTR, GETDEC, PUTCRLF unresolved external.

Please tell me what libraries are to be added and in the code and also the steps to include libraries.

```assembly
DOSSEG  
.186  
.model large  
.stack 200h

.data

Prompt1  db  'Enter integer:#$'  
N        dw  ?  
Nth      dw  ? 
MsgEcho  db  'The input was:$'  
MsgOut   db  'Nth term of Fibonacci sequence : $'  
MsgEnd   db  'Exiting Program  $'  

   .code  
   extrn PutStr: FAR, PutCrLf: FAR  
   extrn GetDec: FAR, PutDec: FAR

ProgramStart   PROC


   mov ax,@data  
   mov ds,ax
  
   mov dx,OFFSET Prompt1           
   mov ah,9                            
   int 21h                           
 
   call    GetDec                         
   mov N,ax       

   mov dx,OFFSET MsgEcho               
   mov ah,9                                
   int 21h                               

   mov ax,N     
   call    PutDec                      
   call    PutCrLf
   call    PutCrLf

   push    OFFSET N                   
   call    NFib                     
 
   mov dx,OFFSET MsgOut                   
   mov ah,9                               
   int 21h                              
 
   mov ax,Nth   
   call     PutDec
```

This is how I implemented half code but it shows error as shown in above picture

---

Comment: Where are these routines defined?

Comment: I dont know how to add them. But, when i downloaded masm32 lib,and tried to add it but again got error, as, couldn't open file. Could you please tell me steps and what library file is to be added?

Comment: A 32 bit library like masm32.lib is not going to work on 16 bit DOS.

Comment: Are you sure you sure you're using irvine32, not irvine16?  If so, that's the problem.

Comment: Yeah, Am sure am using irvine32,are there any other libraries to be included @PeterCordes

Comment: Tell me what kind of what kind of library should be used for this. I am new to this@fuz

Comment: Irvine32 is for 32-bit mode under Windows, not (AFAIK) 16-bit mode under DOS.  Also, it has function names like `ReadDec`, not `GetDec`.  http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/source/irvinelib/readdec.htm

Comment: I downloaded masm lib fiile and wrote in the code as,INCLUDE C:\masm\lib\Irvine32 after using readdec and writedec, and its showing error as. error A10000: cannot open file C:\masm\lib\Irvine32  ...I am stuck at these two errors from quite a long time. Please guide me @PeterCordes

Comment: As others have pointed out to you already, you're trying to use a Windows library (Irvine32) in code written for DOS. That **will not work**. You'll either have to switch to using the Irvine16 library instead, or rewrite the rest of your code for Windows. Take a look at some of the many examples that are included with the Irvine libraries.